# Facebook Like Box not working for my account

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I need to display my Facebook timeline in Like box which I create from below link.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Now when I put my Facebook page url, it doesn't show anything.
My FB page url : facebook.com/bhupendra.kumar.7773

But it works with this page url : facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers

I have gone through the API documentation and came through some access token which are short life. Can anyone help me on this and let me know what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can use the likebox plugin for a profile, it shall be a facebook page like /FacebookDevelopers.